Android UWA App Crashing in Single App Kiosk Mode - Need Help Debugging
My UWA App gets crash in both outside of the Kiosk mode and in kiosk mode Single app. When I check the system log in event viewer
The server waWhaKiosk_1.0.0.8_neutral__bn4vn44xxjckm!waWhaKiosk did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.
And in kiosk mode it try's to open and shows the error as attached below.
Need solution to the above error and need my appx to run in kiosk mode

What platform does the app run on? Android?

Windows platform

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does a blank UWP project reproduce the same problem? Have you tested it on other devices?
